# Apache - RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Tags: windows, apache, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess like this.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^media/([^/]+) download.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^json/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) jsonfeed.php?module=$1&method=$2&params=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?q=$1,$2,$3,$4 [NC,L]
```

Everything works fine until i have image with three directories. For example something like

```
http://localhost/upload/html/.thumbs/2.jpg
```

With URL similar to this last rule is applied.
File exists. It loads fine without rewrite engine.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` set applies only to the one following `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the fact that you used the `[L]` directive.  The subsequent rules do not take into account whether the exists check or directory check succeed or fail.  One solution is as follows:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^media/([^/]+) download.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^json/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) jsonfeed.php?module=$1&method=$2&params=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?q=$1,$2,$3,$4 [NC,L]
```

A more compact solution is to deal with the existing things first, like so:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^media/([^/]+) download.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^json/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) jsonfeed.php?module=$1&method=$2&params=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?q=$1,$2,$3,$4 [NC,L]
```